# What's in a stormtrooper's utility belt?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, stormtroopers

In *A New Hope* when Luke and Leia are trapped at the gap within the Death Star, the the grappling hook that they use to swing across appears to come directly from the Stormtrooper utility belt that Luke kept:

How did Luke know that it was there*, and what other equipment is inside that belt?

*In the scene where it's used, it looks like the hook might have been accessible from outside whatever compartment held the cord and thus easily discoverable, but nothing in the movie (that I'm aware of) seems to confirm that.

Comment: Are you sure that hook wasn't bat-shaped?

Comment: Great question. I've always been curious about this too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### What do Stormtroopers keep in the utility belts?

This is answered in *Ultimate Star Wars*, a fully-canon DK reference book published in 2015:

[image]

> Stormtroopers are equipped with a utility belt containing a variety of equipment, including a compact toolkit, power packs, and energy rations. The belt may also contain a comlink, macro binoculars, and a grappling hook.

Reports that stormtroopers also carry [Vader-shapped throwing stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batarang) and [Rebel-repellant spray](http://batman-news.com/2013/07/16/10-strangest-batman-movie-moments/) remain unsubstantiated.

### How did Luke know the hook was there?

According to the novelization by Alan Dean Foster, Luke discovers the grappling hook entirely by accident:

> Reaching up to the point at the panel holding the unreachable controls, Luke's hand caught on something at his waist. A frustrated glance downward revealed the cause - and engendered a bit of practical insanity.
>
> The cable coiled tightly in small loops was thin and fragile seeming, but it was general military-issue line and would have supported Chewbacca's weight easily. It certainly ought to hold Leia and himself.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars* Chapter X</sup>

Interestingly, this is contradicted in Ryder Windham's junior novelization, where Luke already knew about the belt's contents, evidently having rifled through the pockets upon his escape from the trash compactor:

> The hatch for trash compactor 32-6-3827 adjoined a dusty, unused hallway. Han and Luke had removed their stormtrooper armor but retained the troopers' white utility belts, each of which carried blaster power cell containers, a tool kit, and a grappling hook attached to a fibercord reel.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Luke thought, There's got to be a way out of this! Looking up, he spotted an outcropping of large metal pipes that jutted down from above. Then he remembered: My stormtrooper utility belt has a grappling hook.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope (Junion Novelization)* Chapter 11</sup>

Though, it should be noted, the two explanations aren't wholly incompatible.